# How to get current EntityManager in JPA without spring?

Tags: java, jpa

I'm working on a homework that using JPA but without spring.
It has service layer and repository layer.
I try to begin transaction in service and call save or update from repository and then commit in service.
But how to get Current EntityManager in repository?
My cod is like this:

Service:

```
public void save(Entity entity){
    var em = factory.createEntityManager();
    var t = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        t.begin();

        repository1.save(entity);

        // For saving one to many relation 
        repository2.save(entity.getChildEntity());

        t.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        t.rollback();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
// I don't want to pass EntityManager to method

public void save(T entity) {
    var em = ?      // How can I get EntityManager hear?

    em.persist(entity);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to inject entityManager to bean?

Comment: @ScaryWombat please don't link to that site. Their tutorials and articles are really low quality, and often downright wrong (many code samples don't even compile or teach how to do things wrong).

Comment: I don't know how to inject Gurkan İlleez :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found a safe way to get Current EntityManager in current thread.

I lust link so just sharing code that I want get your feedback and opinions.
I think in this way I can even user Aspectj too.

```
public class EntityManagerUtil {
    //for holding EntityManager in current thread
    private static final ThreadLocal<EntityManager> THREAD_LOCAL;
    
    static {
        THREAD_LOCAL = new ThreadLocal<>();
    }
    // singleton creating EntityManagerFactory 
    private static class LazyHolder {
        private static final EntityManagerFactory ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY =
                Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence-unit");
    }

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        return LazyHolder.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY;
    }

    public static EntityManager getCurrentEntityManager() {
        EntityManager entityManager = THREAD_LOCAL.get();

        if (entityManager == null) {
            entityManager = getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
            // set your flush mode here
            THREAD_LOCAL.set(entityManager);
        }
        return entityManager;
    }

    public static void closeCurrentEntityManager() {
        EntityManager em = THREAD_LOCAL.get();
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
            THREAD_LOCAL.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EntityManagerProvider {

   private static final EntityManager entityManager;

   public EntityManagerProvider() {
      EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.example.factory");
      this.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
   }
   
   public static EntityManager getEntityManager() {
       return entityManager;
   }
}
```

Second Approach :

```
public class EntityManagerProvider {

   private static final EntityManager entityManager;

   private EntityManagerProvider() {}

   public static synchronized EntityManager createOrGetEntityManager() {
        if(entityManager == null) {
           EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("com.example.factory");
           EntityManagerProvider.entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();
           return EntityManagerProvider.entityManager;
        }
        
        return EntityManagerProvider.entityManager;
   }
}
```

You need to create entityManager once and use it everywhere. I don't know where you create factory class but you can create entityManagerProvider class after creation of factory class.

You can simply call EntityManagerProvider.getEntityManager() to receive entityManager from class.

Please note that you don't need to initialize everywhere you can do it once and use it everywhere.

SecondApproach is better you can use it simply everywhere. EntityManagerProvider.createOrGetEntityManager method will give you entityManager.

Comment: Autowire it how? There is no spring.

Comment: I read it as spring application you are right then you have to configure it. I will change answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can simply get from a class

Comment: next question will be "how to get EntityManagerFactory "

Answer (score 0):

In your first snippet of the service I see that you have a `factory` and there you create an `EntityManager`. So the `factory` exists...

Take your factory and make it accessible everywhere in your program. How?
Create a class specific only to creating the factory and the hibernate session. There you create public static getters for the fields that you need (such as the `factory` and `EntityManager`).

Example:

```java
public class HibernateUtils
{
    public static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

Comment: But my project is JPA and I want to do it with JPA. My factory is EntityManagerFactory.

Comment: Then do the same thing for your JPA implementation. You create your factory somehow right? Then create it in this helper class and make it available through static getters...

Comment: And please if your question has no connection to hibernate, remove the tag.

Comment: Renis1235 I removed hibernate tag But can I use JPA persistence.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml same time to resole this?

Comment: Does your first snippet of code work? Are you able to create a factory? If yes problem solved check my implementation. If no, then you have to go deeper and select a JPA implementation (such as Hibernate)

Comment: I can create factory with : Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my_pu");

Comment: Then perfect, do what I have done above and fetch your factory using the getters of the helper class.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, the use of Services and Repositories is a further abstraction of JPA.
If you want to use JPA without Spring, you can inject EntityManager using standard JavaEE/JakartaEE technologies, that is what Spring does under the hood.

Otherwise, if you want to do it by yourself, keep in mind that JPA is a standard for which there are a couple of implementations.

Let's take in consideration Hibernate, go to read the docs, stick with EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager instead of SessionManager (specific to Hibernate).

You can instantiate an EntityManager as:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my_PU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

The "my_PU" is a persistenceUnit that you need to define.

More info here: [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbrj/index.html#:~:text=A%20persistence%20unit%20defines%20a,the%20persistence.xml%20configuration%20file](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbrj/index.html#:%7E:text=A%20persistence%20unit%20defines%20a,the%20persistence.xml%20configuration%20file).